# How can I differentiate views with the same id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a viewpager containing 5 pages. each page is inflated by the same xml file. I put the pages in a FrameLayout array. so the first page is corresponding to f[0] and so on.  how can I replace the entire f[0] with something else using fragmentManager.replace()? the page's xml has an id R.id.page. I have tried `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(f[0].findIdByName(R.id.page,new Frame()).commit();` but it's not working. please help

Comment: You can use different tag to distinguish your fragments. Then use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tagName")` to find you fragment, and replace it.

Comment: but `replace( )` requires an int id as the first argument. and findFragmentByTag returns a fragment object. Could you further explain your method?  I find a workaround by overwriting the original id with an unique one  inside inflate function.

Comment: You remove them firstly, then add your new fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you supplied the replace method with only one parameter. Is this not a compiler error instead of run-time issue?

Valid syntax options:

- replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
- replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)

Sample code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, myFragment, "myFragment A");
```